# What is the maximum filter size that can be used in keras convolution layers?

Tags: keras

I got this error when I increased the filter_size, How to fix it ?

F tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.cc:172] Check failed: size >= 0 (-15981903872 vs. 0)

Looks like it is an overflow (on int 64 !!)

Also, 
Total params: 284,182,346.0
Trainable params: 284,181,998.0
Non-trainable params: 348.0

Comment: What was the filter size? If the filter size you tried is not huge (which is what is normally done), the problem is not exactly the filter size, but the total amount of parameters of the entire model. That said, there is no clear limit, it will depend on the entire model.

Comment: the filter_sizes are in the range of [48, 48*81], from what I know that shouldn't be a problem. Weirdly enough, It's working fine on my local machine (the error was thrown on an AWS instance) !!

Comment: Hmm, maybe this is an important info to add to the question. I have no idea about how that works...